# MAMP mySQL not starting after OS X - El Capitan version 10.11.6 update

Tags: mysql, mamp

MAMP mySQL not starting after OS X - El Capitan version 10.11.6  update. Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: I found the answer here:
http://juanfra.me/2013/01/mysql-not-starting-mamp-fix/
type in mac terminal: killall -9 mysqld

Comment: Yes. I did try to stop the server but it did not help. I did search for help before asking the question. Kind of wish I had not updated OX so soon after the update came out.

Comment: I was surprised to find that an old answer was still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
http://juanfra.me/2013/01/mysql-not-starting-mamp-fix/

type: killall -9 mysqld   (in mac terminal_